# Display hash (or fragment Identifier) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My DNS hosting points a domain to my website (Stealth forward) so the domain that shows in my website is like `www.mydomain.com`, my website is based on SPA (Single page) design and that pages are accessed through fragment identifiers like (#home, #aboutus, etc).

The problem is the forward is stealth so the URL in the browser does not show the hash when navigating to pages.

How can I deal with this with Javascript? How can I make the hash (#home, #aboutus) in the browser URL?

Can this be easily be done with plain JS or I need jQuery for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I manager links in SPA:

Each anchor tag (or button for that matter) gets explicit hash like this:

```
<a href="#action=doSomething&param1=5&param2=10">My Title</a>
```

You can generate hash like above easily like this:

```
var urlHash = "#" + $.param({ action:"doSomething", param1: 5, param2: 10});
```

I don't attach any event handlers to these anchors at all. They are really just plain anchors in HTML. Instead I use delegated event to catch hashchange event. One very easy way to do this is using [JQuery BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). There are numerous advantages in doing this including the fact that your users can bookmark fragments in SPA or send those URLs in emails because they show up in browser just like normal URLs. They also go in history so users can use back and forward buttons just like normal website.

Here's the sample code that listens to hashchange events which will be triggered whenever user clicks on above anchor:

```
    //Global event handler for hash change for above type of anchors
    $(window).bind("hashchange", function (e) {
        var action = e.getState("action");
        if (action === "doSomething") {
            var param1= e.getState("param1");
            var param2= e.getState("param2");

            doSomething(param1, param2);
        }
        //else ignore unknown state
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer correctly however, what I need to show the hash in the browser URL despite of the fact of the DNS stealth forward.